# Keeping track of "real" world coordinates while using Floating Origin

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl

In my game, I attempt to use a 'floating origin' method to prevent model warping from floating point imprecision. 
Every game loop, I check to see if my player position 
(sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz))
is a certain distance from the moving origin (starts at 0, 0, 0) Whenever the player is a certain distance away from the origin, I move the player back to 0, 0, 0, along with everything else, and then set the moving origin to the players last position.

However, I am having difficulty keeping track of the player's 'real' position, since the origin keeps moving, should I use a grid system instead?

What would you recommend?

Comment: Aren't you storing the difference between current origin and real origin?

Comment: I suppose I am, but I'm still having trouble using that to calculate my 'real position'

Comment: Well if you know by how much your world is shifted (i.e. the difference between current origin and real origin) you only need to add your players position to the shifted-by value to get the real value.

Comment: I suppose so, although the calculations are not very precise. Every 'origin shift', it seems that what we think is the 'real' origin shifts a little by 4 or something

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, because there is always a trade-off between the speed of single precision and the accuracy of doubles.

- I keep track of the shifts using a double precision accumulator, so
  that at any time, I can use the double Vector3d to make accurate
  calculations.
- For distance, it is faster to compare the distance
  squared, and use doubles for that in large scale systems, because if 
  you square single precision values for Earth scale or larger, then
  they quickly overflow and you lose accuracy.
- Here is a [demo](https://youtu.be/shXsuJDkk5M) where I use single precision for the high speed rendering per frame stuff and, in the back end, doubles for periodically checking distance, proximity etc.